# Homotopy groups O(N) and SO(N): $\pi_m(O(N))$ v.s. $\pi_m(SO(N))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I have known the data of $\pi_m(SO(N))$ from this Table:
[image]

I wonder whether there are some useful information that I can relate $\pi_m(SO(N))$ and $\pi_m(O(N))$?

Here is the difficulty somehow posted by MO to obtain $\pi_m(O(N))$, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99663/homotopy-groups-of-on

But generally there seem to be some relations, like this:
[image]

Can I get the full Table of $\pi_m(O(N))$ from $m=1$~$10$ and $N=2$~$11$ precisely? Any literatures?

Comment: $SO(N)$ is the connected component of the identity of $O(N)$, so all of their $\pi_k$ agree, $k \ge 1$.

Comment: In the answer of the MO post you give there are also fibrations $SO(n-1)\rightarrow SO(n)\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ and $SO(n)\rightarrow O(n)\xrightarrow{det} \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow Spin(n)\rightarrow SO(n)$. The first uses the action of $SO(n)$ on $S^{n-1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, the second is the determinant and the third is the universal cover.

Hence all of $O(n)$, $SO(n)$, $Spin(n)$ have the same higher homotopy.

Comment: @Tyrone, thanks, +1, this is a great summary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $O(N)$ consists of two connected components which are both diffeomorphic to $SO(N)$. So $\pi_0(O(N)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$, $\pi_0(SO(N)) = 0$, and for $m \geq 1$, $\pi_m(O(N)) = \pi_m(SO(N))$.

As for $\operatorname{Spin}(N)$, note that is it a double cover of $SO(N)$. When $N = 1$, we see that $\operatorname{Spin}(1) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ so $\pi_0(\operatorname{Spin}(1)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and all its other homotopy groups are trivial, while for $N = 2$ we have $\operatorname{Spin}(2) = S^1$ which has first homotopy group $\mathbb{Z}$ and all higher homotopy groups trivial. When $N \geq 3$, $\operatorname{Spin}(N)$ is the universal cover of $SO(N)$ so $\pi_1(\operatorname{Spin}(N)) = 0$ and for $m \geq 2$, $\pi_m(\operatorname{Spin}(N)) = \pi_m(SO(N))$.

The groups $\pi_m(SO(N))$ for $1 \leq m \leq 15$ and $1 \leq N \leq 17$ are given in appendix A, section 6, part VII of the *Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics*. The table can now be found on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+group#HomotopyGroups).

Comment: Can you happen to comment also $_k(pin())$? if we already know $_k(())=_k(pin()/\mathbb{Z}_2)$? Thank you! (There is a long exact sequence of homotopy groups, but I wonder can you say the explicit answer directly.)

Comment: For $N \geq 3$, we have $\pi_1(Spin(N)) = 0$ and $\pi_k(Spin(N)) \cong \pi_k(SO(N))$ for $k \geq 2$. The remaining cases follow from the isomorphisms $Spin(1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $Spin(2) \cong S^1$.

Comment: Many thanks, let me make sure $_(\mathbb{Z}_n)$. Is that $_0(\mathbb{Z}_n)=\mathbb{Z}_n$, and $_(\mathbb{Z}_n)=0$ for $k\geq 1$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.